# Java regular expression that find the attributes of the class

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-negation

I am new to regex and trying to find out a regex that recognizes the standard fields of a class.

so far I have

```
private (double|int|char|String|boolean) .+
```

it is assumed that only the types above will be used and modifier is only private and the name follows the standard of the Java naming standard and convention. however I could not figure it out how to eliminate the brackets () as they are part of the regex. as some methods could be matched:

```
private String regex(){
  return "hello";
}
```

how do I eliminate the ()?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expand your `.+` to more strictly follow the [Java identifier naming requirements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) and then require either a semicolon or assignment operator after that.

Something like (rough approximation for the requirements):

```
private (double|int|char|String|boolean) \\w+\\s+[=;]
```

However, you're going to have to have a heck of a time trying to parse every possible way the grammar could be written with other field modifiers (`transient`, `final`, `static`) that can be in any order, generics, etc.

You'll probably want to figure out what your end goal is and look for a more reasonable approach.

Comment: :- thanks this has already solved the problem, by the way, how would I implement the final as optional I have tried (final)? but did not work

Comment: `(final|)` meaning "final or nothing".  `?` means 0 or 1 of a single character. Beware of different keyword ordering.